# Novas áreas em português além do StackOverFlow

Tags: debate, suporte, comunidade

Existem varias comunidades interessantes como o `Code Review`, `The Workplace`, `Programmers` etc. Muitas vezes algumas perguntas que se encaixam nessas comunidades mais específicas acabam sendo postadas no SOpt.
Por que não há essas comunidades em português? Como ocorre o processo para criação?

Comment: Já houveram várias tentativas para criar outros sites PT, mas por enquanto a SE não pode abrir um novo site em Português devido a falta de CM's para os novos sites. Veja aqui o porquê da proposta do  Super User PT ser fechada na Area 51, que é onde se fazem propostas de sites novos.

Comment: @JorgeB. Faltou o link!

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2543/super-user-em-portugu%C3%AAs-por-que-o-projeto-foi-fechado/2545#2545

Comment: Mathematics em português: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3867/132 - Mais uma tentativa frustrada.

Comment: Já agora mais uma http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/87631/arduino-brasil

Comment: Apesar não estar diretamente ligado ao assunto, vale a pena perguntar. Já viu a proposta para criação de um site sobre a Língua Portuguesa? Caso ache válido, faça um commit lá.  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64172/portuguese-language

Comment: **Warning**: Esse tópico está sendo monitorado por Tim Post, *behave youselves*.

Comment: @re22 Hahaha acompanhei agora isso e já dá medo desta pergunta ser fechada também!

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3919/ampliando-o-escopo-do-stackoverflow-pt

Answer (score 11):

Vou tentar responder sem entrar em politicagem, porque acho que todo mundo já gritou o que tinha que gritar em relação a esse assunto. Ainda assim, uma resposta "oficial" em Português no nosso Meta não é uma má ideia.

---

A resposta simples e direta para a pergunta "Por que não há essas comunidades em português? Como ocorre o processo para criação?" é:
**Mais comunidades em Português fazem parte dos nossos planos no futuro**

No momento nós temos Stack Overflows em Português, [Japonês](http://ja.stackoverflow.com) e [Russo](http://ru.stackoverflow.com), com Espanhol vindo nos próximos meses. Depois disso o mais provável é que sites internacionais, SO ou não, não sejam mais abertos por um tempo.

Abrir novos sites nunca foi um trabalho simples, mesmo em Inglês. O processo se tornou simples ao longo de 6 anos de aperfeiçoamentos, coisa que ainda não ocorreu com as outras línguas. Basta lembrar que houve 1 ano entre o SOen e o Super User e Server Fault, e mais 1 ano até começarem a aparecer outros sites em Inglês.

E isso sem contar o fato de que, em uma empresa primariamente anglófona, gerenciar esses sites em Inglês é um trabalho mais fácil, que pode ser dividido entre várias pessoas, em que a equipe de desenvolvimento pode participar ativamente. Nada disso acontece nas outras línguas.

Além disso, os sites internacionais têm um outro conjunto de desafios por conta da tradução, diferentes alfabetos (o SOpt, por exemplo, não aceitava acentos nas tags e a busca não funcionava para palavras acentuadas), e outras idiossincrasias.

O SOpt iniciou o processo de criação de sites internacionais, há mais ou menos 18 meses. De lá pra cá muita coisa melhorou, e muita coisa precisa melhorar. Comunidades são coisas frágeis, principalmente ao nascerem, e não queremos criar um novo site sem que tenhamos certeza de que vai ser possível prestar o melhor suporte possível. Não seria justo com os participantes, e não é assim que fazemos as coisas aqui.

Nós estamos trabalhando agora em:

1. **Unificar a categorização das strings traduzidas entre os sites internacionais.**
   Deixando, por exemplo, que as tags criadas pelos tradutores em Japonês apareçam no projeto em Português. Assim, fica mais fácil pra todo mundo saber o contexto das strings, e encontrar o que precisa ser consertado.
2. **Impedir que mudanças no texto em Inglês sejam refletidas nos sites internacionais**
   Não acho que vamos ter uma solução perfeita, mas não queremos que partes do site voltem a aparecer em Inglês de repente, como já aconteceu no passado com a tela de votos para fechar.
3. **Aproximar as comunidades internacionais da equipe que toma conta delas**
   É algo que ajudou os sites em Inglês no passado e que, apesar de não ser totalmente reproduzível aqui, é possível melhorar o gargalo que existe hoje entre os sites internacionais e o resto da empresa. Pra que vocês tenham mais participação e estejam mais cientes do que estamos fazendo.

Quanto mais o processo de gerência dos sites internacionais for otimizado, menos trabalho vai ser pra conseguir ficar de olho em mais 1, mais 5 ou mais 10. É isso que queremos no futuro, mas que não é possível dar conta no momento.

Comment: Agradeço a Buda pelo item (1)